# Networking search + image downloads operations in OperationQueue: Operations vs URLSession's delegateQueue

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I need to perform this scenario:

- User provides some search parameters which I should use to call an URL and parse its response (I use an `URLSessionDataTask` for this).
- That response is a JSON that may contain several image URL's I should then call to download (I use as many `URLSessionDownloadTask` as images URL's I got), and then show them in an `UITableView` (one image per cell).
- User should be able to cancel the current search to start a new one, so previous complete search + downloads process could be still in progress at that moment.

Moreover, for the data task (initial search) I use an `URLSessionConfiguration.default`, and for the several download tasks I use `URLSessionConfiguration.background`.

Initial search (data task) and the set N image downloads (N download tasks) are serial, meaning that I need to get the response of the initial search to start the image downloads. But I need the N image downloads to be concurrent, since I am going to show each image in its corresponding cell once that certain image has finished being downloaded.

On the other hand, all these networking operations (search + downloads) need to be asynchronous, of course.

My question: I have seen that `URLSession` has an initializer that can be provided an `OperationQueue` as `delegateQueue` parameter. Regarding this option, I think I should do something like this:

```
self.queue = OperationQueue()
self.queue.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
self.defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: queue)
self.backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)
```

Then I should be able to call `self.queue.cancelAllOperations()` when user starts a new search.

Would this be the correct approach to my scenario? Would the images be downloaded concurrently?

The other option I have thought about is to create that same `OperationQueue` but, instead of passing it as `delegateQueue` to both `URLSession`, to model the data task and the download tasks as `Operation` and call `self.queue.addOperation`.

Is there any difference in behaviour and performance between this two options? Which one should be the appropriate for my scenario? Or would it be better a different approach (in such case, which one)?

**EDIT:**

Other option I'm thinking of is: each cell to have a reference to its own `URLSessionDownloadTask` and call to download its image when cell is reused, but cancelling the task when a new download is going to be performed, something like that:

```
var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

func downloadImage(imageUrl: URL) {
    downloadTask?.cancel()

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: request)
    downloadTask?.resume()
}
```

Here I don't use the operation queue, just cancel the task. Is this correct and better option? Should I then call `downladTask?.cancel()` when the cell is dequeued?